# Firebase Cloud Functions is deleting nodes instantly instead of deleting after 2 hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Functions to delete nodes after 2 hours on firebase.However, when I add a node, it is being deleted as soon as it is created inside the database

My index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const CUT_OFF_TIME = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 2 Hours in milliseconds
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/posts/{randomID1}/{randomID2}/timestamp')
.onWrite(function(change) {
    var ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
    var now = Date.now();
    var cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
    var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
    return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      // create a map with all children that need to be removed
      var updates = {};
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        updates[child.key] = null;
      });
      // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
      return ref.update(updates);
    });
  });
```

My database struture:

```
  "posts" : {
    "randomID1" : {
      "randomID2" : {
        "timestamp" : 1557842159
      }
    },
    "randomID3" : {
      "randomID4" : {
        "timestamp" : 1557842203
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamps are stored in seconds, not in milliseconds. Since your code uses `Date.now`, which returns the timestamp in milliseconds, you're comparing values that are 1000x off.

The simplest solution is to:

```
const CUT_OFF_TIME = 2 * 60 * 60; // 2 Hours in seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing timestamp in milliseconds with timestamp in seconds.

`var cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;` - The cutoff value is in milliseconds

You need to change the `CUT_OFF_TIME` and convert `Date.now()` to seconds.