# Cloud Function deletes node instantly instead of after two hours based off timestamp (delete-old-child-nodes not working)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement the "delete-old-child-nodes" Cloud Functions example (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes). When the directory is written to, it should delete all nodes that are 2+ hours old. However, it just deletes all nodes no matter what.

I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133351/firebase-cloud-functions-is-deleting-nodes-instantly-instead-of-deleting-after-2) that describes the same issue. However, I believe the cause is different. The user was storing his timestamp in seconds, while the cutoff was in milliseconds. In my code, both are in milliseconds.

This is the current index.js code, it is exactly the same as the Firebase example, except for that I call the timestamp "lastUpdated," and not "timestamp."

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const CUT_OFF_TIME = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/decks/{pushId}').onWrite(async (change) => {
  var ref = change.after.ref.parent; 
  const now = Date.now();
  const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
  const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('lastUpdated').endAt(cutoff);
  const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');
  const updates = {};

  ref = ref.parent.child('deckLocs')

  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  });

  return ref.update(updates);
});
```

This is my database structure

```
"xxxx-9d272" {
 "decks" : {
    "randomID12345" : {
      "lastUpdated" : 1558460300472
    },
    "randomID67890" : {
      "lastUpdated" : 1558460300472
    }
 },
 "deckLocs" : {
    "randomID12345" : {},
    "randomID67890" :{}
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you're expecting the delete to be delayed 2 hours from the time the function is invoked?  There is no database operation that delays itself.  Everything completes as fast as possible.  The example you linked to is just showing how to delete old nodes, not delay their deletion.

Comment: @DougStevenson I intend to delete old nodes like how the example is supposed. to function. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Did you already try to troubleshoot it yourself? E.g.: what is the path of `ref ` when you log it? And what is the value of `cutoff` when you log it? And what is the value of `updates` when you log it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have tried to troubleshoot before. I just tried it again three times and the first two times it did not delete the new entry, but the third time it did delete. ```Cutoff``` is definitely correct and reports a time of two hours ago (1558486099798). ```updates``` reports ```{ '-LfSRADxaZMciyZ8eLfm': null }``` and the path of ```ref``` is ```https:/xxxxx.firebaseio.com/decks```, which is the directory it should be searching through.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think I may have found the issue but I have another question. Before I was returning ```ref.update(updates)```, I was changing ```ref``` to point to another path by saying ```ref = ref.parent.child('deckLocs')```. I forgot to mention this in my original question, but I was trying to delete a node with the same ID as the old one in ```decks```  in another path (```deckLocs```) at the same  level as ```decks```' I updated my data structure in the post to reflect that. How do I best go about doing this and delete a node with the same ID at a different location?

Comment: If `updates` reports `{ '-LfSRADxaZMciyZ8eLfm': null }`, then that is all that will be deleted by the original code. If you've found the cause of the problem, consider posting it as a self-answer so that others can potentially benefit from it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your help. I took your suggestion and made an answer. I have one last question: How would I also apply the recorded updates to the ```deckLocs``` directory and not just the ```decks``` directory that was originally queried and is currently being updated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to apply the updates to another directory and the line `ref = ref.parent.child('deckLocs')` was causing issues. If it's gone it works as intended.